# How can I compact the VHD file with Ubuntu?

Tags: hyper-v, ntfs, hyper-v-server-2008-r2, ext4, zero-fill

I use windows server 2008r2 with role Hyper-V. The guest system is Ubuntu 12.04 LTC. It is situated on the dynamic virtual hard disk.

I want to compact this VHD (The real size is 50 GB, 360 GB on the disk). But I can not do this, because the Ubuntu file system is not NTFS.
**What do I need (gparted, sdelete, ...) for solving this problem?**

The main problem is that the filesystem is not NTFS, but ext4.

***The answer:***

1) Download systemrescuecd

http://sourceforge.net/projects/systemrescuecd/files/sysresccd-x86/3.8.1/systemrescuecd-x86-3.8.1.iso/download

2) Add this .iso to the quest OS Ubuntu

3) Start this virtual machine

4) Use zerofree

```
zerofree /dev/sda1
```

5) Poweroff this virtual machine

6) Use Hyper-V manager (Edit -> defragmentation)

This vhd was 360 Gb. Now 70 GB.

Comment: If you want to answer your own question, please post an *answer*, not an edit to the question itself.

Comment: consider `fstrim` in 2019, especially for ext4 under LVM https://superuser.com/questions/1491437/how-to-properly-compact-hyper-v-dynamic-sized-vhdx-files-for-linux-vms

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Poweroff your VM, backup the VHD, and run another virtual machine (I use [SystemRescueCD](http://www.sysresccd.org/SystemRescueCd_Homepage) since it's small and fast) that has the ext4 partition available to it, i.e., a HD for SysRescue (but don't mount it!).  From the SysRescue VM, run '[zerofree](http://manpages.ubuntu.com/manpages/raring/man8/zerofree.8.html)' on the ext4 partition, poweroff that VM, and then use your Administration Website to compact the VHD.

Comment: I begin do it (download SystemRescueCD, then zerofree /dev/sda1), but I do not know can I compact this VHD in Windows (after all free space will be null)

Comment: Try the [Hyper-V Manager](http://virtuatopia.com/index.php/Creating_and_Configuring_Hyper-V_Virtual_Hard_Disks_(VHDs)#Modifying_Existing_Hyper-V_Virtual_Hard_Disks).

Answer (score 5):

I can confirm: zerofree is working to compact virtual disk files

BUT: you don't need to use any rescue CDs or to mount the VHDX in another virtual machine:

```
sudo apt-get install zerofree
```

Boot into [recovery mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/172319), then run:

```
zerofree /dev/sda1
```

After that, we have to start the optimization for the virtual disk file. On the server hosting the VHDX file, create the following file ShrinkVhdx.ps1:

```
[CmdletBinding()]
Param(
    $VHDFiles
)

# Find the disks
foreach($VHD in $VHDFiles){
    Write-Verbose "Working on $VHD, please wait"
    Write-Verbose "Current size $([math]::truncate($(Get-VHD -Path $VHD).FileSize/ 1GB)) GB"
    
    Mount-VHD -Path $VHD -NoDriveLetter -ReadOnly
    Optimize-VHD -Path $VHD -Mode Full

    Write-Verbose "Optimize size $([math]::truncate($(Get-VHD -Path $VHD).FileSize/ 1GB)) GB"
    Dismount-VHD -Path $VHD
    
    Write-Verbose ""
}
```

And now run the file and enjoy the released disk space :-)

```
ShrinkVhdx.ps1 .\hdd1.vhdx
```

Comment: This depends on the filesystem if it's XFS you are out of luck using zerofree.

Answer (score 2):

The process appears to be

- Backup your current VHD file.
- Use Snapshot manager to delete/merge any snapshots.
- Zero fill the unused disk space

viz

```
sudo apt-get install secure-delete 
sudo sfill -llz .
```

This creates a file called `oooooooo.ooo` filled with `0`s. You should repeat the sfill command on all partitions I guess.

Note this isn't quick either, it will take hours if not days to complete.

- Compact
- Profit

Comment: thanks, but I do not have the internet on the machine with hyper-v and vhd with linux. So I can not do "sudo apt-get install secure-delete"

Answer (score 1):

1) Download systemrescuecd

http://sourceforge.net/projects/systemrescuecd/files/sysresccd-x86/3.8.1/systemrescuecd-x86-3.8.1.iso/download

2) Add this .iso to the quest OS Ubuntu

3) Start this virtual machine

4) Use zerofree

zerofree /dev/sda1

5) Poweroff this virtual machine

6) Use Hyper-V manager (Edit -> defragmentation)

Comment: Hyper-V manager does not have a (Edit -> defragmentation)

Answer (score 0):

I did try to start Systemrescuecd in a 2nd gen machine. But it didn't work, so I created a new 1st gen machine and added the VHDX to it. systemrescuecd started. I didn't do any operations. Removed the 1st gen machine and put the VHDX back in the original machine. Then Ubuntu didn't start up at all. Only Grub-menu.

See my post here:
[Hyper-V Ubuntu vhdx scsi ide](https://serverfault.com/questions/685458/hyper-v-ubuntu-vhdx-scsi-ide)

So be aware of this, and do take backup (I didn't this time)...

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by checking some parameters in the following files:
/sys/block//queue/discard_granularity
/sys/block//queue/discard_max_bytes
if either have a 0 it's probably not supported by your hardware + software configuration.

Here's a full tutorial on doing this at: http://www.1337admin.org/uncategorized/compacting-virtual-disks-on-generation-2-linux-hyper-v-2012-r2-vms/