# Hyper-V Ubuntu vhdx scsi ide

Tags: ubuntu, hyper-v, vhdx

I have a Hyper-v 2nd gen Ubuntu machine (scsi).
I did add the vhdx file to a 1st gen (ide) machine (not as start disk, but to try to use some system rescue cd tools to srink the vhdx zerrofill). I didnt have time to do the actions, so I just put the vhdx file back in the original machine.
Then it didn't start up as expected. I was prompted with a grub menu with Ubuntu boot options, but none of the alternatives makes the machine to boot up.

How do I restore this?

Followed this steps:
[How can I compact the VHD file with Ubuntu?](https://serverfault.com/questions/551053/how-can-i-compact-the-vhd-file-with-ubuntu)
But didn't find zerrofill.

[image]

[image]
Starting Ubuntu Recovery mode gives this:
[image]

Comment: We need more detail.  A log of the boot errors, a screenshot something.  I am really not sure what you changed here, and I have no idea what errors you are getting.  Without having any of the above I doubt anyone can help you.

Comment: I think my main question is: Can a vhdx file be changed only if I insert it into another machine with diferent Hyper-V generation? I did just boot the machine up with the disk attached, and then change back again. No operations where made to the disk.

Comment: Do you have a backup you can revert to?